# Failed to mount "partition name" - "Not authorized to perform operation" - in Xfce Debian

Tags: debian, mount, xfce, ntfs, privileges

I have Debian 10 with Xfce installed. I can't open any of my NTFS hard drives using icons on desktop and in Thunar. I can mount them with the `mount` command, though. My user is added to the `sudoers` group and also to the `sudoers` file, and it can use `sudo` in terminal, but for some reason Xfce seems to fail to ask for password. I also have Gnome installed and it asks for password and mounts these drives fine. Also, USB drives mount without any problem both in Xfce and Gnome.

What should I do?

[image: "Mount Failed" error pop-up]

Comment: Have you tried to mount it in Gnome and copy a record for your drive mounted in gnome from /etc/mtab into /etc/fstab? Or you like to input password every time/boot?

Comment: I don't mind entering password every time it seems like default behavior. As far as I remember it was like so when I installed debian before.

Comment: you should check the permission attributes to the filesystem and partition, and whenever you mount try to use "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/file" etc. etc. also creating a active fstab entry for automatic mounting is smart too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the dialog window that asks for a password is actually a separate program called "PolicyKit authentication agent" which for some reason wasn't installed. So i installed `policykit-1-gnome` and now I can enter the password and mount drives.